# Change the button from disabled='true' to 'false'

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have written a code regarding a submit form. When I click the `button(Download)`, the status is disabled, and I want to make it enabled, but if I add an alert box between submit and make the disable false, it works. If I remove the alert box, it doesn't work. Is that the time problem or else? How can I solve it?

How can I change the button from `disabled='true'` to `'false'`?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="fm" class="btnStyleFunc" onclick="disabled='true';submitform()">
                                    <a><span>Download</span></a>
                                            </div>
```

---

```
function submitform(){
    var element1 = document.getElementById('form');

    if (element1 != null){
    } else {        
    }

    document.getElementById('form').submit();
    alert('test');   // <--------
    document.getElementById('fm').disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `<button type="submit"><a><span>Download</span></a></button>` instead of `<div...`? `div` doesn't technically have a `disabled` context or an [attribute in the specs (see the Global Attributes link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/div#Attributes).

Comment: it is because i don't want use a buuton, it is the requirement so i use div as a button. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent someone from double-submitting (by disabling the Download "button" after the initial click)?

Comment: in fact, i want to make the submit like a light, at first, when i move the the mouse to the submit, it the text will light on, when i click the sumbit, it will turn off the light just a second. Then, the submit will return the the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function disabledFunc(id)
{
    var divObj = document.getElementById(id);
    divObj.disabled = false;
}
```

And call the function with the button id:

```
disabledFunc('fm');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's still doesn't work. 
Is there any time problem or action problem.
Why i add alert between submit and diabled= false, the result will be ok .....

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div id="fm" class="btnStyleFunc" onclick="this.disabled=true;submitform()">
                                    <a><span>Download</span></a>
                             </div>
```

Of course, the element is a DIV and not a button, so I don't know how well `disabled` will work on it...

Answer (score 0):

As Farish and MrXenotype have pointed out, the "disabled" attribute is meaningless to a `div` element.  It can be added dynamically but won't affect the behavior.  But I understand why you might want to use a `div` instead of a button, especially if you have spent time customizing your style sheet to get it to look the way you want.

I think you can get the behavior you want though by making a small change:

```
<div id="fm" class="btnStyleFunc" onclick="this.onclick=null;submitform()">
   <a><span>Download</span></a>
</div>
```

Basically when your onclick handler executes, you disconnect it from the `div` element.  Now when someone clicks your "button" a second time it will do nothing.  During the `onclick` you might want to also change your class to something other than btnStyleFunc - perhaps a new class called `btnStyleFuncDisabled`.  Then you can modify your style sheet so that any `div` element with that class appears greyed out.

```
<div id="fm" class="btnStyleFunc" 
     onclick="this.className='btnStyleFuncDisabled'; this.onclick = null; dosubmit(this)">
   <a><span>Download</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just for the record (and I agree with you), `button`s can be styled *much more simply* than `input` buttons, *and* can contain markup themselves. FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

```
<div id="fm" class="btnStyleFunc" onclick="disabled='true';submitform()">
```

will create a global variable `disabled` with the string value 'true', and

```
 document.getElementById('fm').disabled = false;
```

compares the `disabled` property of an element with id "fm" to the boolean value `false`.